# How to query a restful webservice using Python

Tags: python, web-services, http, python-requests

Writing a Python script that uses [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib to fire off a request to a remote webservice. Here is my code (test.py):

```
import logging.config
from requests import Request, Session

logging.config.fileConfig('../../resources/logging.conf')
logr = logging.getLogger('pyLog')
url = 'https://158.74.36.11:7443/hqu/hqapi1/user/get.hqu'
token01 = 'hqstatus_python'
token02 = 'ytJFRyV7g'
response_length = 351

def main():
    try:
        logr.info('start SO example')

        s = Session()
        prepped = Request('GET', url, auth=(token01, token02), params={'name': token01}).prepare()
        response = s.send(prepped, stream=True, verify=False)

        logr.info('status: ' + str(response.status_code))
        logr.info('elapsed: ' + str(response.elapsed))
        logr.info('headers: ' + str(response.headers))
        logr.info('content: ' + response.raw.read(response_length).decode())


    except Exception: 
        logr.exception("Exception")
    finally:
        logr.info('stop')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following successful output when i run this:

```
INFO test - start SO example
INFO test - status: 200
INFO test - elapsed: 0:00:00.532053
INFO test - headers: CaseInsensitiveDict({'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'set-cookie': 'JSESSIONID=8F87A69FB2B92F3ADB7F8A73E587A10C; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'date': 'Wed, 18 Sep 2013 06:34:28 GMT'})
INFO test - content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserResponse><Status>Success</Status> .... </UserResponse>
INFO test - stop
```

As you can see, there is this weird variable 'response_length' that i need to pass to the response object (optional argument) to be able to read the content. This variable has to be set to a numeric value that is equal to length of the 'content'. This obviously means that i need to know the response-content-length before hand, which is unreasonable.

If i don't pass that variable or set it to a value greater than the content length, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 590, in _readall_chunked
    chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 562, in _read_next_chunk_size
    return int(line, 16)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 0: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in main
    logr.info('content: ' + response.raw.read().decode())
  File "\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 167, in read
    data = self._fp.read()
  File "\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 509, in read
    return self._readall_chunked()
  File "\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 594, in _readall_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(351 bytes read)
```

How do i make this work without this 'response_length' variable? 
Also, are there any better options than 'Requests' lib?

PS: this code is an independent script, and does not run in the Django framework.

Comment: Why not use the public API of requests? You are tinkering with internals, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [public API](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) instead of internals and leave worrying about content length and reading to the library:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.verify = False
s.auth = (token01, token02)
resp = s.get(url, params={'name': token01}, stream=True)
content = resp.content
```

or, since `stream=True`, you can use the `resp.raw` file object:

```
for line in resp.iter_lines():
    # process a line
```

or

```
for chunk in resp.iter_content():
    # process a chunk
```

If you *must* have a file-like object, then `resp.raw` can be used (provided `stream=True` is set on the request, like done above), but then just use `.read()` calls *without* a length to read to EOF.

If you are however, *not* querying a resource that requires you to stream (anything but a large file request, a requirement to test headers first, or a web service that is explicitly documented as a streaming service), just leave off the `stream=True` and use `resp.content` or `resp.text` for byte or unicode response data.

In the end, however, it appears your server is sending chunked responses that are malformed or incomplete; a [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) includes length information for each chunk and the server appears to be lying about a chunk length or sending too little data for a given chunk. The decode error is merely the result of incomplete data having been sent.

Comment: Tried this - 

s = requests.session()
response = s.get(url, auth=(token01, token02), params={'name': token01}, stream=True, verify=False)

for line in response.iter_lines():
 logr.info('output: ' + line)




Got this error - 

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    return int(line, 16)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: invalid continuation byte

During handling of ... occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
_readinto_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(bytes(b[0:total_bytes]))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(351 bytes read)

Comment: @QuestMonger: Sounds like you have a web service that is not sending data correctly.

Comment: @QuestMonger: What happens when you do *not* stream and just read the content in one go?

Comment: if i dont use 'stream=True' option, i get the same error as in my original post - 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 0: invalid continuation byte'

Comment: @QuestMonger: You are getting incomplete data; and if the data is cut off in between a multi-bytpe UTF8 character you have a problem.

Comment: @QuestMonger: The content cannot be read in one go instead of in chunks?

Comment: @QuestMonger: it looks as if the server is sending a malformed chunked response, perhaps the server is broken? Chunks are sent with content length information *per chunk* and the chunk read fails with an incomplete response.

Comment: yea i was afraid this would be a source issue.
btw if you are referring to 'response.raw.read(response_length).decode()', i don't believe data is being read in chunks. as per original explanation, the value of 'response_length' is set to the length of the content (351). So the entire conent is being read in once, and decoded.
i need to test this against a different webservice that provides streaming, chunky responses.
fyi - the webservice is a shitty vmware product. just wanted to get that out there.
thanks for all your help @Martijn Pieters.

Comment: @QuestMonger: The exception is inside the `http.client` library code, which is responding to a server sending chunked responses, based on headers the server sends. Yes, you requested that 351 bytes be read, but that is not the cause of that incomplete response exception.

Answer (score 1):

The server you request use "chunked" transfer encoding so there is not a content-length header. A raw response in chunked transfer encoding contains not only actual content but also chunks, a chunk is a number in hex followed by "\r\n" and it always cause xml or json parser error.
try use:

```
response.raw.read(decode_content=True)
```

Comment: ok tried this - 
{       s = Session()
        prepped = Request('GET', url, auth=(token01, token02), params={'name': token01}).prepare()
        response = s.send(prepped, stream=True, verify=False)
        logr.info('content: ' + response.raw.read(decode_content=True))
}

got the same error as above - 
{Traceback (most recent call last):
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
During ... exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(351 bytes read)}